# Redirect user to dynamic url

Tags: rules, tokens

I am writing a custom rule, I do not know how to approach getting the correct URL for the redirect.

I have a page - website.com/content/newsletter-activity-001 that needs to redirect an anonymous user to website.com/content/activity-001 until they are logged in.

I have a reference field in 'newsletter-activity-001' that holds the title to 'activity-001'. I want to write a rule that will apply this for newsletter-activity-002 and so on as the site content grows.

How do I dynamically pull that url out and place it into the redirect path? Would tokens do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens `[site:current-page:path]` & `[site:current-page:url]` will retrieve the current Drupal path & the full URL, respectively.

Comment: Thank you! I was taken a different direction so this thought process won't get finished. I appreciate your feedback that helped me.